Specifying Application ID URL
Context
I'm building an Office 365 add-in - to be run in Outlook, both desktop and web -, and I'm at the stage where I want to try logging the user in and getting an access token. However, I'm running into trouble getting the login to work.
The Troubles
I have registered the application in Entra, and I have an App ID for it. I filled out my WebApplicationInfo element in the manifest, and that's where the problems start.
Rejected sideloading
If I use the app URL Entra gives me, and get something like this
<WebApplicationInfo>
  <Id>foo</Id>
  <Resource>api://foo</Resource>
  <Scopes>
    <Scope>User.Read</Scope>
    <Scope>Mail.Read</Scope>
    <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
    <Scope>email</Scope>
    <Scope>profile</Scope>
    <Scope>openid</Scope>
  </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>

Outlook will reject the sideload - but will not give any reasons why - and nothing will work (obviously).
The Resource element looks strange, but according to Microsoft docs, this is by-design as this is how Entra enforces uniqueness in URLs.
If I comment this element, things are working, but - as expected - calling the auth APIs will give an error as the add-in is not signaling auth capability.
Client error
If I "fix" the app URL to look something like an actual URL, such as this one
<WebApplicationInfo>
  <Id>foo</Id>
  <Resource>api://localhost:3000/foo</Resource>
  <Scopes>
    <Scope>User.Read</Scope>
    <Scope>Mail.Read</Scope>
    <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
    <Scope>email</Scope>
    <Scope>profile</Scope>
    <Scope>openid</Scope>
  </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>

Outlook will accept the manifest for sideloading and I am able to call the Javascript APIs to initiate login, but this will predictably fail, because it's pointing to a localhost origin. Furthermore, the Microsoft documentation for the element shows the example as
<WebApplicationInfo>
  <Id>12345678-abcd-1234-efab-123456789abc</Id>
  <Resource>api://contoso.com/12345678-abcd-1234-efab-123456789abc</Resource>
  <Scopes>
    <Scope>Files.Read.All</Scope>
    <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
    <Scope>openid</Scope>
    <Scope>profile</Scope>
  </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>

where the host is also set to a non-random value, leading me to believe the Entra UI is giving me the wrong information.
The question
How do I get the login working from within an add-in? What do I need to specify in the WebApplicationInfo element in order to be able to use the JS APIs?

When you are developing, you are typically using a local dev server at a localhost:xxxx domain. When you move to staging you are typically using a public domain. Don't for get to update your Entra registration when you go to staging. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2

@RickKirkham That was a good reference, other docs didn't mention I need to "fix" the URL Entra gives me by default. The weird thing is, I tried setting it to a production domain - just to get logs - or a local server, but nothing apart from localhost:3000 is accepted, anything else results in a rejected sideload (no details given of course /s)...

Sideloading is for localhost. When you change the URL to a staging or production URL, you have to publish some other way. See Publish, especially Network share.

@RickKirkham Thanks, I'll take a look at this doc as well. <gripe> It would be awesome if the official tutorial included these pieces of vital information without me having to resort to asking around on SO... </gripe>
